# Need to trim the names of file names

Tags: rename, filenames, ksh

[image]I have files in UNIX directory which have a unique number starting with, i have to remove the unique id followed by '-' from the file name and need to have regular file.

Example: 32456113-report.pdf

Required File name in the database: report.pdf

I have file names of all kind of extensions .pdf, .doc, .xls, .txt but have the same number in the front.

I am using winscp to test or view the data and i am running a shell script by registering it as a host concurrent program in oracle apps.

Comment: Not sure I understand where the database fits in.  Are you using another language to interact with a database?

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I believe a simple bash script as follows would work

```
for f in * ; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | cut -d- -f2)"; done
```

If you don't like the echo to cut nonsense, I can look up the  string rules in bash for you.

Comment: I fixed up your code a bit to include more quotation marks. Also, [don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: :)  Thanks!  I should have known better than parsing ls, but was too blinded by not immediately knowing the string rules of bash.

Comment: Apparently the original poster is using ksh.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..... my file name is changed but it was like this $(echo 34178248-BPI_TAX_EX--.pdf | cut -d- -f2). Any suggestion, i really appreciate for your time

Comment: You can use `cut -d- -f2-` instead.

Comment: i didnt get you what do you mean to use cut -d- -f2-,  i am new to shell script, i am actually a plsql developer.

Comment: Instead of `cut -d- -f2` like in my answer, use `cut -d- -f2-`.  Basically, take the second and all following fields of the input to cut.

Comment: No it didnt work, the filename changed to $(echo 34178248-BPI_TAX_EX--.pdf | cut -d- -f2-)

Comment: mv -- "34178248-2640006.pdf" "${34178248-2640006.pdf}" when i use this i got the desired result, can i automate the process for all the files in the directory

Comment: @sam: That is a very, very strange way of doing that. This might work to automate it: `for f in * ; do mv "$f" "$(eval echo \${$f})" ; done`. The mechanism you are using is called parameter substitution. The value to the left of the first hyphen is supposed to be a variable. If it doesn't exist, the text on the right is substituted. Since there are no variables with the same names as your numbers, the text on the left is always substituted. See [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: $(eval echo ${34178248-2640006.pdf}) all the file names changed this way when i used it in script, i dont understand why i cant automate it, is there any other way i can do it.. thanks again

Answer (score 4):

```
for f in *; do 
    regular="${f#*-}"
    echo "$f => $regular"
done
```

This parameter expansion (`${f#*-}`) removes, from the start of the variable's value, the shortest string that ends with a hyphen (see [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)). So:

```
$ f=32456113-summary-report.doc
$ echo "$f => ${f#*-}"
32456113-summary-report.doc => summary-report.doc
```

Comment: mv: cannot rename /tmp/34178248 to /tmp/34178248//34178248: Invalid argument
/u01/R2ID10/R2ID10appl/xxps/11.5.0/bin/XXPS_MULTIPLE_EMAIL3: bad substitution
/u01/R2ID10/R2ID10appl/xxps/11.5.0/bin/XXPS_MULTIPLE_EMAIL3
Program exited with status 1

Comment: This code might not work for ksh, which is what @sam is using.

Comment: This code does work in ksh, that's where I tested it. @sam, please show what you're actually running, edit your question with more details please.

Comment: mv -- "34178248-2640006.pdf" "${34178248-2640006.pdf}"  when i use this i got the desired result, can i automate the process for all the files in the directory

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perl-rename`.

```
perl-rename 's/[0-9]*-//' <files>
```

Depending your OS/distro, this utility may be called `rename`. To be safe, use the `-n` flag with `perl-rename` to do a dry run before actually renaming any files.

Comment: ksh[6]: syntax error at line 6 : ';' unexpected.... i got this when i run the above command in winscp

Comment: If i use rename it says not a valid command

Comment: How are you running the command? Is it part of a script?

Comment: I run it in both script as well as in winscp too, when i run in winscp i got this error

Comment: I've never used ksh or winscp so I may be missing something, but I find it strange that you're receiving an error on line 6 when you're only running one line.

Comment: mv -- "34178248-2640006.pdf" "${34178248-2640006.pdf}" when i use this i got the desired result, can i automate the process for all the files in the directory